# Playing notes or simple sounds on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio

I would like to play simple sounds that can be varied at runtime, for example being able to play sounds at different frequencies.

Basically, I would like to be able to produce a simple melody at runtime, and then play it. How do synthesizing apps do that? I'd imagine that there is a way to do it via `CoreAudio`.

**Is there a way to do that using the SDK?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to create PCM samples of audio waveforms, you can create a waveform for your desired note duration at your desired frequency and volume, and feed that raw waveform data to either the Audio Queue API or the Audio Unit RemoteIO API.

Here's one slightly longer [description of how to play](http://www.musingpaw.com/2011/04/iphone-programming-how-to-play-tone-at.html) a tone using these APIs.

Answer (score 3):

http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

This is a most excellent resource,  it will get you up and running with audio units.

This is great too: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do that.  The simplest would be to record all the notes you need, and then use a timer to create a sequence.  Try AVAudioPlayer first, that's the easiest way. If you need to work with the audio data directly you can use Audio Queue Services or OpenAL.

Comment: +1  the question doesn't make it clear how much control is needed.  Hollance's OpenAL SoundBank Player (on GitHub) provides a very easy solution if you just need a polyphonic player.